# How to run Redshift, and Redshift Plasmoid in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gui, autostart, plasma, redshift

[Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) briefly appears on the taskbar at startup or when run and pops out of existence. I've installed [Redshift Plasmoid](https://github.com/simgunz/redshift-plasmoid) for a GUI, but I can't get that to run either, and won't show up when I check my software.

Comment: Any error message if you start `redshiftautostart`?

Comment: no, it seems to be awaiting further input in the terminal. However, nothing else happens.

Comment: I think this is down to problems with the kde, though i've got the ppa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have followed the instructions more closely (specifically the "cp" bit) for KDE, installed eclipse and it's cdt, and installed the plasma desktop itself.